# PHP slider based on current posts from active category in Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, post, slider, categories

Hello fellow community,

I'm pulling my hair off for the past 3 days.

I tried many post / gallery / sliders plugins on Wordpress, and I cannot get the result I was looking for.

Basicaly what I would like to do is to generate a dynamic slider based on the current posts from the active category page. The posts are all listed under the same category. The slider must display ONLY the posts belonging to the current category.

I tried to customize the category.php page with Slider Revolution but it only retrieve "the most recent" post and not the rest.

I tried with many others plugins but they all display posts from other categories.

Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: you can create your own slider, with something like BXslider - and then just make the loop items only contain the images and links in a `li`, should be fairly straight forward.

Comment: read the docs, for the correct syntax

Comment: thank you, for example here's one of my article id <article id="post-82" class="post-82 post type-post status-publish format-standard has-post-thumbnail hentry category-marie">  the category would be : category-marie.

Comment: Where should I make this loop with the li property in the category.php page ? <?php get_header(); ?>
 <!-- section -->
    <section role="main">
 <div class="wmffcontainer">
 
     <div class="post-padding"></div>
        

            <?php get_template_part('loop'); ?>
            
            <?php get_template_part('pagination'); ?>
        
        
           
 </div>
 </section>
    <!-- /section -->

<?php get_footer(); ?>

Answer (score 0):

So a bxslider could look something like this

```
<?php 
if ( have_posts() ) : ?>
    <div class="bxslider">
      <?php while ( have_posts() ) : ?>
           <?php the_post();?> 
            <div class="whateverClassHere">whatever content here <?php echo get_the_title(); ?></div>
      <?php endwhile; ?> 
   </div>
<?php endif; ?>
```

And then you would initiate it with Jquery

```
$('.bxslider').bxslider(); //read the docs for settings here.
```